# Using HostFXR to host a C# runtime that hotloads user made C# assemblies

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to write a C++ application that hosts a C# runtime using the HostFXR API. I want to get this C# runtime to load user-made C# assemblies dynamically.

So what I have right now is three .dll files called `Host.dll`, `FunctionLibrary.dll` and `UserLibrary.dll`.

The `Host.dll` file is what HostFXR hosts in C++.

This is what `Host.dll`'s code looks like

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Host;

public unsafe class Program
{
    private static byte[] ToMemoryStream( Stream input )
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        input.CopyTo( ms );
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    private static Assembly LoadAssembly( string path )
    {
        return Assembly.Load( ToMemoryStream( File.OpenRead( path ) ) );
    }

    [UnmanagedCallersOnly]
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            FunctionLibrary.Module.Test = true;

            Assembly userLibrary = LoadAssembly( @"W:\\Visual Studio 2022\\UserLibrary\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0\\UserLibrary.dll" );
            Type? userModule = userLibrary.GetType( "MyLibrary.MyModule" );
            MethodInfo entryPoint = userModule?.GetMethod( "OnStartup", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public );
            entryPoint.Invoke( null, null ); // Print out the value of FunctionLibrary.Module.Test, expected to == true
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ex );
        }
    }
}
```

This is `FunctionLibrary.dll`'s code:

```
namespace FunctionLibrary;

public static class Module
{
    public static bool Test = false;
}
```

And finally, this is `UserLibrary.dll`'s code:

```
using FunctionLibrary;

namespace MyLibrary;

public class MyModule
{
    public static void OnStartup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( FunctionLibrary.Module.Test );
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is for the console to print out the value of `FunctionLibrary.Module.Test`, which I set to true in the `Host.dll`'s code;

But when I run my C++ application, the console prints out this error message:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FunctionLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'FunctionLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at MyLibrary.MyModule.OnStartup()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Host.Program.Main() in W:\Visual Studio 2022\Host\Program.cs:line 30
```

I'm really stuck right now, mainly because I just don't know what other avenues I can try to get this working the way I want. I appreciate any help I can get to understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's the trouble with Assembly.Load(byte[]), there is no loading context to help find any dependent assemblies.  Very unclear why it is favored here, Assembly.Load(string) trivially solves the problem.  Otherwise you'd have to implement the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to help out.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. The reason I opted for Assembly.Load(byte[]) is to prevent the C# host environment from locking the UserLibrary.dll from being able to be rebuilt, and then reloaded into the C# host environment.

I implemented the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event, and that did get rid of the error and now the program runs. However, the value of FunctionLibrary.Module.Test gets printed out as "False" instead of the expected value "True". It seems like the UserLibrary.dll is using a different instance of FunctionLibrary.dll?

Comment: After some more tinkering, I think I managed to get it to work using AppDomain.AssemblyResolve! When I posted my previous comment, I don't think I was using the event the correct way. But now it seems to return the correct instance of FunctionLibrary.dll!